# How to import excel data from specific rows into EXISTING SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import, sql-server-2012

I need to import an excel spreadsheet into a database. I get the spreadsheet every few months so the amount of data varies each time. Data either starts from row 7 or row 8 which contain header information and does not have specific row to end. The amount of data varies from 400 to 10000s rows. Above and below the data is information I don't need. I am trying to create an automated procedure in SQL server to read only data I want and import into an existing table.

I was thinking of creating a condition where the data must be read from the header information which starts from either row 7 or row 8 all the way to the first blank row. How do I create a condition like this?

I am aware of the OPENROWSETS. The problem with OPENROWSETS is it can specified to read from a specific row and I don't think it can be specified to end reading at a blank row.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the spreadsheet data, I would suggest reading the entire worksheet into a temp table, trim "off the fat" and insert the meat into the real table.

Comment: Your answer is a bit too vague. Do you really need the spreadsheet? I mean I explained what it is pretty much like.

Comment: Only reason I say without seeing spreadsheet is I don't know if you are able to use OPENROWSETS to load the entire spreadsheet into a temp table.